# specifying XML schema for a XML document for a particular string

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I had xsd as follows

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="College">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It must allow only 2 values Example 
Only ABC and CBS are allowed

```
<college>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Name>CBS</Name>
</college>
```

which should not allowed

```
<college>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Name>CBS</Name>
<Name>XYZ</Name>
</college>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a countable number of options you can use an enumeration to restrict them. Replace your `xs:element` declaration with this:

```
<xs:element name="Name" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ABC"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="CBS"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: The solution proposed by @DaliusSidlauskas is equivalent to this one. Any one of them will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern matching

```
<xsd:element name="elementName">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="/^[ABC|CBS]$/"></xsd:pattern>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```